# Change cmd + f behavior in macOS Sierra

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra

When searching for text in macOS apps (Chrome, Sublime, etc.), <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> opens search/find (or whatever it's called) with the previous search filled in.

Is there a way to change this behavior to make it use the highlighted text instead (similar to the behavior of Windows' <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>)? This would allow highlighting a word, hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>return</kbd> to search, without needing to paste in the word or use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>. I know this is possible in some app settings (for example, Sublime has a setting called `find_selected_text`) but I'm looking for a way to do it, preferably globally, from the OS.

**tl;dr:** How can I make <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> automatically search for the highlighted text in MacOS Sierra?